# Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.anko:anko:1.10.5

Tags: kotlin, anko

i have add $anko_version in build.gradle(project)
and the add dependencies in build.gradle(app) but Failed when i try to sync.

I just implemented, and it works

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5"
```

Comment: You are going to have to show us your build, we can't really diagnose your problem with just a text description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the latest version for anko, and that is

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.5"
```

There is no version like 1.10.5. Check the [anko documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/README.md)